# Force close during TabView navigation?

Tags: android, tabs

In my Activity there is a TabView  with 3 Tabs , each tab has a ListView and a Button.
When i navigate the tabs using the D-Pad on the emulator there is no problem, but when i use the scroll-wheel(mouse) to navigate the view and then click in the View there is a ForceClose. I think its got something to do with "touchmodechange" but not sure how to handle this. Really appreciate any help...

```
12-23 19:14:25.352: ERROR/ActivityThread(116): Failed to find provider info for android.server.checkin
12-23 19:18:09.184: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(226): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
12-23 19:18:09.224: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(226): java.lang.IllegalStateException: The content of the adapter has changed but ListView did not receive a notification. Make sure the content of your adapter is not modified from a background thread, but only from the UI thread.
12-23 19:18:09.224: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(226):     at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1428)
12-23 19:18:09.224: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(226):     at android.widget.AbsListView.onTouchModeChanged(AbsListView.java:1888)
12-23 19:18:09.224: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(226):     at android.view.ViewTreeObserver.dispatchOnTouchModeChanged(ViewTreeObserver.java:591)
12-23 19:18:09.224: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(226):     at android.view.ViewRoot.ensureTouchModeLocally(ViewRoot.java:1877)
12-23 19:18:09.224: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(226):     at android.view.ViewRoot.ensureTouchMode(ViewRoot.java:1861)
12-23 19:18:09.224: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(226):     at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1652)
12-23 19:18:09.224: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(226):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-23 19:18:09.224: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(226):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
12-23 19:18:09.224: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(226):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4203)
12-23 19:18:09.224: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(226):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-23 19:18:09.224: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(226):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
12-23 19:18:09.224: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(226):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:791)
12-23 19:18:09.224: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(226):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:549)
12-23 19:18:09.224: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(226):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)



private void fillData(int tab)
    {
        Cursor cursor;
        Long millis;
        String tempstr;
        //query table and obtain cursor 
        if(tab==0)
            cursor=dbAdapter.getAllRemindersCursor();
        else if(tab==1)
            cursor=dbAdapter.getAutoRemindersCursors();
        else if(tab==2) 
            cursor=dbAdapter.getUserRemindersCursors();
        else
            cursor=dbAdapter.getAllRemindersCursor();

        results.clear();

        //populate the ArrayList using the cursor
        if(cursor!=null)
        {
            if(cursor.moveToFirst())
            {
                Log.d("Msg","Cursor at first item");
                Log.d("Msg",cursor.getCount()+" items in cursor");
                do
                {
                    millis=cursor.getLong(1);
                    tempstr=cursor.getString(2);
                    tempstr=" "+tempstr+"\n"+" "+dtf.format(millis);
                    results.add(tempstr);
                    category.add(cursor.getInt(4));
                    Log.d("Msg","message and type items added");
                }
                while(cursor.moveToNext());
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Log.d("Msg","Cursor is empty");
        }

        if(tab==0)
            lv1.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,results));
        else if(tab==1)
            lv2.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,results));
        else if(tab==2)
            lv3.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,results));
        else
            lv1.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,results));
    }
```

This method is called every time onTabChangedListener is triggered. Other wise there is 
nothing much else at present in this Activity.

Comment: Are you using onFocusChangedListner anywhere in you code ?

Comment: @R.daneel.olivaw Actually at the moment all i use is onTabChangedListener

Comment: Can you show your code please.

Comment: @Pavan More I have added the primary function i the activity to my qusestion. The rest of the code is just initializations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are sharing the same `results` List for all of your Adapters. This list is directly referenced inside the adapter, so when you switch a tab you're updating the adapter on all of them (this is why you get an IllegalStateException). Instead of reusing the results variable, simply create a new one inside your filldata method, there's no need (that I can see from the code above) to use the same one. I believe you could have also just used CursorAdapters and not bothered the intermediate List.

Comment: correct me if i am wrong , but my data is being updated properly. if the reason for forceclose is the common ArrayList then it should happen every time i change the tab , but the forceclose occurs only when i navigate using mouse-wheel and then click on any item in the layout within the tab.

Comment: Hmmm, I'm not sure why it only happens in that scenario, but I'm pretty sure you shouldn't be reusing the List. You _do_ see that you're setting and updating the same exact list on all of the adapters, right (b/c there's never a `new List()`, only the `clear()`)? If you look at the [ArrayAdapter code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.0.1_r1/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.java#ArrayAdapter.init%28android.content.Context%2Cint%2Cint%2Cjava.util.List%29), when you pass a list it just gets used directly, no copy is being made.

Comment: The idea is that the list is used as a temp storage , each time the tab is changed result is cleared, and re-populated with data generated from the query to the table. Any changes made to the table becomes visible at this point.

Comment: I understand what you're trying to do, but it can't work that way because each ArrayAdapter will store a reference to it. You _have_ to create a completely new list each time. This is perfectly fine.

Comment: from what is see the forceclose occurs when i click the layout after any of the tabs gain focus , even if the tab does not have focus any more.

Comment: OK for a test i used seperate arraylists for each tab and the problem is gone. Thanks man..